# Validating strings using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to convert strings into numbers using `NSNumberFormatter`. In my application, input strings with more than 2 digits after the decimal point are not valid, i.e., `@"3.1"` and `@"3.14"` are valid inputs, but `@"3.141"` is not.

The documentation for `NSNumberFormatter` says that `setMaximumFractionDigits:` "[s]ets the maximum number of digits after the decimal separator allowed as input by the receiver."

So, I was surprised when this code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"3.141"];
NSLog(@"%@", number);
```

accepted `@"3.141"` and gave me the following output:

```
3.141
```

I was expecting the conversion of `@"3.141"` to fail (and return `nil`) because it has more than the maximum number of digits allowed after the decimal separator.

Obviously I'm not understanding something basic here. Does `NSNumberFormatter` not use `maximumFractionDigits` as part of validating string input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from the lack of other answers or any indication of this in the official documentation: No, `NSNumberFormatter` doesn't support comprehensive validation when parsing numbers, and `maximumFractionDigits` is only relevant when formatting numbers. This seems to be consistent with with `sscanf`, `strtof` and such.

Answer (score -1):

NSNumberFormatter's `numberFromString:` method return an `NSNumber` if it can parse the string correctly, or nil if it cannot.